# Why predict() in R has to be done on test data

Tags: r, testing, predict

In the below code, do I need to follow approach 1 or approach 2. 
I am confused why the test data to be used in predict as per approach 1.
Would be great if someone can explain it in detail.

```
train <- sample(nrow(sales), nrow(sales)*0.6) 
test <- sales[-train]
```

Approach 1

```
fit <- lm(y~x,data=train)
predict(fit,data=test)
```

Instead can't I do this way:
Approach 2

```
fit <- lm(y~x,data=train)
predict(fit,data=train)

fit1 <- lm(y~x,data=test)
predict(fit1,data=test)
```

Comment: What's the error/output?

Comment: am not getting any error ?  Just want to know which approach is better and why its better

Answer (score 0):

Speaking generally, `predict()` using a model trained on training data, applied to training data, can only be used for introspection about the model as trained. Applying that to (ideally independent) test data makes sense either as a validation of the trained model or a use of the model for further prediction.

In other words, they're not different approaches to the same thing; they accomplish completely different things.